# Find the group of permutations on $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ which leaves the symmetric polynomial invariant

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, symmetric-polynomials

> Find the group of permutations on $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ which leaves the symmetric polynomial $x_1 x_2+x_3x_4$ invariant.

What I know about this is as follows:

A polynomial $f(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ is invariant under $S_n$ if for all $\pi \in S_n$
$$f(\pi(x_1), . . . , \pi(x_n)) = f(x_1, . . . , x_n)$$ But here how will I find the permutation such that the polynomial is invariant.

Comment: The 2-cycle $(1,2)$ is in the group. Why?

Comment: Where did you get the question from? $x_1x_2+ x_3x_4$ is not a symmetric polynomial.

Comment: It is a symmetric polynomial.

Comment: By definition a [symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) is a polynomial that is invariant under permutations of its variables. If $x_1x_2 + x_3x_4$ were a symmetric polynomial, then the answer to your question would be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $\sigma\in G$, the group you want to find, then you have: $$\sigma(x_1)\sigma(x_2)+\sigma(x_3)\sigma(x_4) = x_1x_2+x_3x_4$$.

The key here is that the above identity should be thought of as an equality between two polynomials. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Then we can say that $\sigma$ is the identity element also. Except identity is there any?

Comment: no, there are more. look at $\sigma = (x_2,x_1, x_3, x_4)$, for example.

Comment: Even $(1 2), (3,4)$ this will also work.

Comment: yes, but you are looking for all such $\sigma $s that make it work. do you understand the question itself actually?

Comment: (1 2), (3,4), (1 2)(3 4), (1), I think these are the all.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad Keep going. $(1 3)(2 4)$ also works. Now multiply this by some of the ones you have, too.

Comment: @davidP why does it matter if I cannot have $1\to 3$?

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad Sorry, I misread that as a cycle.

Comment: The permutation group acts on the indices not on the values of the polynomial: $$\sigma(x_1)\sigma(x_2)+\sigma(x_3)\sigma(x_4) = x_1x_2+x_3x_4$$ should read: $$x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}+x_{\sigma(3)}x_{\sigma(4)} = x_1x_2+x_3x_4$$